# IBM Worklight - Can we import an existing Xcode project?

Tags: android, ios, ibm-mobilefirst

In IBM worklight we make an application run on multiple platforms like Android, iOS, Windows/Phone...

My question is if I have an Xcode project and I want to make the same project for android, can I import this existing Xcode project in IBM Worklight and make it run for Android also...?

Comment: ujjwal, is your question resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot port an existing native iOS app/project to a Worklight project.
You can either:

- Add the Worklight SDK to make the native app work with Worklight - with slight/considerable adjustments
- Rewrite the app

In your case you will need to rewrite it.

1. You will need to create a new Worklight project and add to it the iPhone/iPad and Android environments.
2. You will then need to re-write the core functionality in the Common folder
3. And any specific environment functionality/design in the environment folders
4. Backend communication is done via Worklight Adapters

You need to go over the [IBM Worklight Getting Started training modules](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/library/) and familiarize yourself with the product as well and not jump ahead.

Comment: what does you mean by "Add the Worklight SDK to make the native app work with Worklight - with slight/considerable adjustments"? can you elaborate more?

Comment: The Worklight SDK will allow you to use native API methods provided by Worklight in order to communicate with the Worklight Server, invoke adapter procedures, use authentication, etc... implementing this is on you, and could be easy or more elaborate, based on your app. You can read more about native development in Worklight in the following Getting Started section: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#native

Comment: Good. Please make as answered.

Comment: would like to, but not sure how, cause Im not the one who started this thread?